# Matching words and vectors in gensim Word2Vec model

Tags: python, vector, machine-learning, gensim, word2vec

I have had the [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) [Word2Vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec) implementation compute some word embeddings for me. Everything went quite fantastically as far as I can tell; now I am clustering the word vectors created, hoping to get some semantic groupings.

As a next step, I would like to look at the words (rather than the vectors) contained in each cluster. I.e. if I have the vector of embeddings `[x, y, z]`, I would like to find out which actual word this vector represents. I can get the words/Vocab items by calling `model.vocab` and the word vectors through `model.syn0`. But I could not find a location where these are explicitly matched.

This was more complicated than I expected and I feel I might be missing the obvious way of doing it. Any help is appreciated!

#### Problem:

Match words to embedding vectors created by `Word2Vec ()` -- how do I do it?

#### My approach:

After creating the model (code below*), I would now like to match the indexes assigned to each word (during the `build_vocab()` phase) to the vector matrix outputted as `model.syn0`.
Thus

```
for i in range (0, newmod.syn0.shape[0]): #iterate over all words in model
    print i
    word= [k for k in newmod.vocab if newmod.vocab[k].__dict__['index']==i] #get the word out of the internal dicationary by its index
    wordvector= newmod.syn0[i] #get the vector with the corresponding index
    print wordvector == newmod[word] #testing: compare result of looking up the word in the model -- this prints True
```

- Is there a better way of doing this, e.g. by feeding the vector into the model to match the word?
- Does this even get me correct results?

*My code to create the word vectors:

```
model = Word2Vec(size=1000, min_count=5, workers=4, sg=1)
        
model.build_vocab(sentencefeeder(folderlist)) #sentencefeeder puts out sentences as lists of strings

model.save("newmodel")
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914287/word2vec-how-to-get-words-from-vectors) which is similar but has not really been answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I found an easy way to do this, where `nmodel` is the name of your model.

```
#zip the two lists containing vectors and words
zipped = zip(nmodel.wv.index2word, nmodel.wv.syn0)

#the resulting list contains `(word, wordvector)` tuples. We can extract the entry for any `word` or `vector` (replace with the word/vector you're looking for) using a list comprehension:
wordresult = [i for i in zipped if i[0] == word]
vecresult = [i for i in zipped if i[1] == vector]
```

This is based on the [gensim code](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py). For older versions of gensim, you might need to drop the `wv` after the model.

Answer (score 10):

I have been searching for a long time to find the mapping between the syn0 matrix and the vocabulary... here is the answer : use `model.index2word` which is simply the list of words in the right order !

This is not in the official documentation (why ?) but it can be found directly inside the source code : https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/3b9bb59dac0d55a1cd6ca8f984cead38b9cb0860/gensim/models/word2vec.py#L441

Answer (score 5):

If all you want to do is map a *word* to a *vector*, you can simply use the `[]` operator, e.g. `model["hello"]` will give you the vector corresponding to hello.

If you need to recover a word from a vector you could loop through your list of vectors and check for a match, as you propose. However, this is inefficient and not pythonic. A convenient solution is to use the `similar_by_vector` method of the word2vec model, like this:

```
import gensim

documents = [['human', 'interface', 'computer'],
 ['survey', 'user', 'computer', 'system', 'response', 'time'],
 ['eps', 'user', 'interface', 'system'],
 ['system', 'human', 'system', 'eps'],
 ['user', 'response', 'time'],
 ['trees'],
 ['graph', 'trees'],
 ['graph', 'minors', 'trees'],
 ['graph', 'minors', 'survey']]

model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(documents, min_count=1)
print model.similar_by_vector(model["survey"], topn=1)
```

which outputs:

```
[('survey', 1.0000001192092896)]
```

where the number represents the similarity.

However, this method is still inefficient, as it still has to scan all of the word vectors to search for the most similar one. The best solution to your problem is to **find a way to keep track of your vectors** during the clustering process so you don't have to rely on expensive reverse mappings.

Comment: thanks! that one i found! no i just need to make it work the other way round: put in a vector, get out a word...

Comment: This is possible, and I've updated my post to show how. But you'll be a lot better off if you can find a way to keep track of your vectors, as the reverse mapping is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

As @bpachev mentioned, gensim does have an option of searching by vector, namely `similar_by_vector`.

It however implements a brute force linear search, i.e. computes cosine similarity between given vector and vectors of all words in vocabulary, and gives off the top neighbours. An alternate option, as mentioned in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35979229/2353472) is to use an approximate nearest neighbour search algorithm like FLANN.

Sharing a gist demonstrating the same:
https://gist.github.com/kampta/139f710ca91ed5fabaf9e6616d2c762b