# Word Embedding to word

Tags: neural-network, nlp, keras, word-embedding

I am using a GloVe based pre-trained embedded vectors for words in my I/P sentences to a NMT-like model. The model then generates a series of word embeddings as its output for each sentence.

How can I convert these output word embeddings to respective words? One way I tried is using cosine similarity between each output embedding vector and all the i/p embedding vectors. Is there a better way than this?

Also, is there a better way to approach this than using embedding vectors?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the question is lacking a lot of details like the library used for word embedding, the nature of the model, and the training data, etc ...
But I will try to give you an idea what you can do in those situations, assuming you are using some word embedding library like [Gensim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gensim).

**How to get the word from the vector**:
We are dealing with predicted word vectors here, so our word vector may not be the exact vector of the original word, we have to use similarity, in Gensim you can use [similar_by_vector](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors.similar_by_vector), something like

```
target_word_candidates = similar_by_vector(target_word_vector,top=3)
```

That's would solve the reverse lookup problem, as highlighted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914287/word2vec-how-to-get-words-from-vectors), given all the word vectors how to get the most similar word, but we need to find the best single word according to the context.

You can use some sort of post-processing on the output target word vectors, this would be beneficial for trying to solve some problems like:

1.How to guide the translation of out-of-vocabulary
terms?

2.How to enforce the presence of a
given translation recommendation in the decoder’s
output?

3.How to place these word(s) in the right
position?

One of the ideas is to use an external resource for the target language, i.e. language model, to predict which combination of words are gonna be used. Some other techniques incorporate the external knowledge inside the translation network itself